# How to use backgroundColor and backgroundImage one on top of another

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am using react/typescript with material UI. I want to use a background image and background color both together like color transparent. Here is my code snippet:

```
 return (
//Todo need to do one more level of refactor   
  <div style={{ flex: 1, backgroundImage: `url("https://Content/images/backgrounds/91.jpg")`, backgroundSize: "cover", height: "100vh", zIndex: 2 }}>
  <Grid
    direction="column"
    alignItems="center"
    container
    justifyContent="center"
    sx={{height: "100vh", backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,235,0.3)', color:'white', zIndex: -1}}>
    <Grid item>
      <Paper>
```

But here only color is displayed, It should be display images also both together with transparent.
Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that using a background image and a linear gradient, this way:

```js
return (
//Todo need to do one more level of refactor   
  <div style={{ flex: 1, background: `linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,235,0.3), rgba(0,0,235,0.3)), url("https://Content/images/backgrounds/91.jpg")`, backgroundSize: "cover", height: "100vh", zIndex: 2 }}>
  <Grid
    direction="column"
    alignItems="center"
    container
    justifyContent="center"
    <Grid item>
      <Paper>
```